# Running a method just once when running pytest in parallel

Tags: pytest

I wrote several tests and  after all tests run finished i want to call a method to send email with the tests report. How this method can be called just once when running in parallel using pytest and xdist?

Comment: You can use custom hookimpls for that. E.g. `pytest_sessionfinish` or `pytest_unconfigure` are guaranteed to run on the master node after worker nodes have exited. You may need additional logic to access the test report though; what exactly do you want to have access to? Or do you want to send some result assembled by a plugin (e.g. send the HTML report file produced by `pytest-html`)?

Comment: pytest_sessionfinish and pytest_unconfigure works in parallel (xdist)?

Comment: What do you mean with _works_? They are called after all tests were executed, regardless of the serial or parallel mode.

Comment: I checked it and pytest_sessionfinish runs for every test in parallel mode

Comment: Then I'm wrong about `sessionfinish`, only `pytest_unconfigure` runs after the tests.

Comment: pytest_unconfigure also runs for every test in parallel mode

Comment: [I can‘t reproduce that](https://replit.com/@hoefling/JuicyInfantilePixels). Feel free to add a [mcve] for the issue, though.

Answer (score 0):

The pytest_sessionfinish function runs at the end of all tests. If you check for the worker input attribute, it will run in the master thread after all other processes have finished testing

```py
def pytest_sessionfinish(session, exitstatus):
    """Insert teardown that you want to occur only once here"""
    if not hasattr(session.config, "workerinput"):
        pass  # whatever you want to do here
```

Source: https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-xdist/issues/271#issuecomment-826396320